# Swipeable does not work with PanResponder React Native

Tags: typescript, react-native, frontend, panresponder, react-swipeable-views

I have seen the same problem with ScrollView with PanResponder, and when I solved it as it says there, I did not succeed, the problem is that on my expo go on web everything works correctly, but if I run expo on ios (I do not know how it works on android, I did not check). My project starts without errors, and allows me to swipe once, calling panHandler once and you can still swipe, but when I finish swiping, the swipe itself does not work, and the console.log that I have in onPanResponderMove is called correctly and constantly as long as I need. In general, I need a panHandler so that when I swipe to a certain point in x, a certain action occurs, either animation or deletion.

```
import React, { Component, MutableRefObject, useMemo, useRef, useState } from 'react';
import { View, StyleSheet, Image, Text, TouchableOpacity,Dimensions,ScrollView, PanResponder,Animated, PanResponderInstance, GestureResponderEvent, LayoutChangeEvent, PointerEvent } from 'react-native';
import { listOfChatsStyle } from '../../Styles/ListOfChatsStyle';
import Message from '../../1HelpFullFolder/Message';
import Chat from '../../1HelpFullFolder/Chat';
import LastMessageStatus from './LastMessageStatus';
import ModeActivity from '../Status Content/ModeActivity';
import { GestureHandlerRootView, RectButton,Swipeable} from "react-native-gesture-handler";

interface ChatProps {
  chat: Chat;
}
interface ForState{
  isSwiped:boolean
}

const { width: screenWidth ,height:screenHeight} = Dimensions.get('window');
class ChatContainer extends React.Component<ChatProps,ForState>{
  private chat:Chat;
  private lastMessage: Message | undefined;
  private position:any;
  private panResponderRight: PanResponderInstance;
  private setIsSwiped(isSwiped: boolean) {
    this.setState({ isSwiped });
  }
  constructor(props: ChatProps) {
    super(props);
    this.state={
      isSwiped:false,
    };
    this.chat=props.chat;
    this.lastMessage=this.chat.listOfMessages.length > 0 ? this.chat.listOfMessages[this.chat.listOfMessages.length - 1] : undefined;
    this.panResponderRight= PanResponder.create({
        onPanResponderMove(e, gestureState) {
          console.log(10)
          
        },
        onStartShouldSetPanResponder:(evt,gestureState)=>true,
        onMoveShouldSetPanResponder: (event, gesture) => {
          if (gesture?.moveX > gesture?.moveY) {
            return false;
          }
          return true;
        },
        onPanResponderRelease(){

        }

      })
  }
  private renderRightActions= (progress:any, dragX:any) => {
    const scale1=progress.interpolate({
      inputRange:[0,1],
      outputRange:[150,0],
    })
    const scale2=progress.interpolate({
      inputRange:[0,1],
      outputRange:[75,0],
    })
    return (
      <View  style={{flexDirection:"row",maxWidth:screenWidth*0.5,minWidth:150}}>
        {!this.state.isSwiped?<Animated.View style={{flex:1,transform:[{translateX:!this.state.isSwiped?scale1:scale2}]}}>
          <RectButton style={[{backgroundColor:"yellow"},listOfChatsStyle.rightAction]}>
            <Text>Notify</Text>
            <Animated.View style={{width:screenWidth,backgroundColor:"yellow",position:"absolute",zIndex:-1,top:0,bottom:0,left:0}}/>
          </RectButton>
        </Animated.View>:<Animated.View style={{flex:1,position:"absolute",zIndex:-1,transform:[{translateX:scale1}]}}>
          <RectButton style={[{backgroundColor:"yellow"},listOfChatsStyle.rightAction]}>
            <Text>Notify</Text>
            <Animated.View style={{width:screenWidth,backgroundColor:"yellow",position:"absolute",zIndex:-1,top:0,bottom:0,left:0}}/>
          </RectButton>
        </Animated.View>}
        <Animated.View style={{flex:1,transform:[{translateX:!this.state.isSwiped?scale2:scale1}]}}>
          <RectButton style={[{backgroundColor:"red"},listOfChatsStyle.rightAction]}>
            <Text>Delete</Text>
          </RectButton>
          <Animated.View style={{width:screenWidth*1.5,backgroundColor:"red",position:"absolute",zIndex:-1,top:0,bottom:0,left:0}}/>
        </Animated.View>
      </View>
    )
  };
  render() {
  return(
  <View>
  <TouchableOpacity 
  onPress={this.handlePress} 
  onLongPress={this.handleLongPress}
  pressRetentionOffset={{ top: 0, left: 0, right: 0, bottom: 0 }}
  activeOpacity={1}

  >
    
    <View style={listOfChatsStyle.helpContainer}/>
    <GestureHandlerRootView>
      <Swipeable renderRightActions={this.renderRightActions}>
    <View   style={listOfChatsStyle.chatcontainer} {...this.panResponderRight.panHandlers}>

    </View>   
      </Swipeable>
    </GestureHandlerRootView>
    </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
  );
}
};


export default React.memo(ChatContainer);
```

I tried to fix it for 3 days for 6 hours, I have already tried everything, but I need panHandler because in another way the coordinates cannot be dynamically obtained, or I do not know about it, but if it is possible, I will also accept it as an answer, thank you very much

Comment: What kind of functionality are you trying to achieve with PanResponder?

Comment: I need that when you swipe to half of the screen on the right side, the right view fills the second, and when you release it, it scrolls completely to the end